# Can Apache play dead for me?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04

I have a little home server I use the sync pictures with my phone. The sync program is in a secret sub-folder. I have noticed from monitoring the logs that there are MANY attack attempts against the root-folder. It seems the bad guys are randomly hitting IP addresses looking for a reply. And Apache is replying (404), so they break out the battering ram and try everything else they know. BAD Apache!

Can I tell Apache to "play dead" on 404 requests so it looks like there is no server even setup and they move on? I don't see any purpose to putting a target on my back by letting Apache talk to them.

To clarify, I know how to make the 404 page blank, but that's not what I need. I need to stop the header and all. Total silence.

Edit: To clarify, I have 2 virtual servers.  I want the default one to play dead when someone scans IP addresses.  The other is TLS secured and the sync software is password protected.

**Bonus Points:  Can you force an exact match to a virtual server name?**  Currently Apache will reply to ANY AND ALL request with the virtual server that best matches the request.  Ick.

Comment: Why would you ever have an internal webserver that you are using to sync pictures from your phone to available to the internet?   It would be much better to only allow connections from known ranges/hosts to stop people from attacking you.  Also change the default port 80 to something else above 1024..

Comment: It's available on the internet so my wife and I can share a folder of pics and files as I travel.  It beats the heck out of texting or emailing 20 pictures.  Don't think of it as internal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. To start decoding a request, Apache first has to accept it. That's sufficient to determine that the server is up.

The first solution that comes to mind is to run Apache on a non-standard port. HTTP is usually available on port 80 (HTTPS on 443 or 8080) and bots will knock on that port. Using something non-obvious (and preferably over 1000) will be sufficient to stop them. You'll still be able to access your files simply by appending `:port_number` after IP/domain. For example `http://example.com:1337` or `http://192.168.1.123:5465`.

That being said, you're relying on [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and that's no good. Your defenses can be broken simply by sniffing your network traffic. Consider adding additional layers of security: password protection, IP whitelisting etc.

Comment: This seems like a good answer.  I'm not sure you can sniff the address of TLS secured traffic.  Even if you can the software requires login, and my password is great.  And I am using white-listing the best I can for a traveler.  Just wanted to maximize my security.

Comment: Also, I'm not relying on obscurity.  I just have it in my arsenal.

Comment: If you're using TLS, then [URL cannot be sniffed, just the hostname](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/20833/68614).